# Avoid dyanmic content's translation in msgstr

Tags: django, transactions

I am using Django translations for ja and de using makemessage. There is a translation in that I don't want to translate dynamic content in de.

I am using the following translations.

```
msgid " and %(level3)s subgroups"
msgstr "und aller Untergruppen von %(level3)s "
```

But now I don't want to use dynamic content 'level3' in msgstr. I simply need need `und aller Untergruppen von`.

so I changed it to

```
msgid " and %(level3)s subgroups"
msgstr "und aller Untergruppen von "
```

but while doing compilemessages it's getting error

```
CommandError: Execution of msgfmt failed: /Users/treeni/treeni_produts/sustain-online/so-web/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:4409: a format specification for argument 'level3' doesn't exist in 'msgstr'
msgfmt: found 1 fatal error
```

Comment: Does your po file have something like this `#, python-brace-format` before the `msgid`? If so, removing it will fix it but I am not sure if that's your case since I was using the fstring format.

Answer (score 2):

Remove any comment which starts with `#, python` before **needed** message.

Example:

Before:

```
#: venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:129
#, python-format
msgid "Value %(value)r is not a valid choice."
msgstr ""
```

After:

```
#: venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:129
msgid "Value %(value)r is not a valid choice."
msgstr ""
```

Good day!